# endwhile and endforeach break wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

Got this piece of code, that is supposed to pull content from the first post of a category in "single" template. To be clear, it's supposed to show that content beside the original post. And with current code, template shows the content of first post, whatever the post it is. When I try to close the loop with endwhile and endforeach, it simply breaks the page, and it doesn't show anything. Just a blank white screen.

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category();
foreach ($category as $cat)
{
    query_posts( array ( 'cat' => $cat->cat_ID, 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 1  ) );
    while (have_posts())
    {
        the_post();
        echo '<a class="fulltitle" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.$cat->cat_name.'</a>';
    }

    $category_id = get_cat_ID($cat->cat_name);
    $category_link = get_category_link($category_id);
  endwhile;
}
endforeach;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `endforeach` or `endwhile` if you're using brackets.

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category();
foreach ($category as $cat)
{
    query_posts( array ( 'cat' => $cat->cat_ID, 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 1  ) );
    while (have_posts())
    {
        the_post();
        echo '<a class="fulltitle" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.$cat->cat_name.'</a>';
    }

    $category_id = get_cat_ID($cat->cat_name);
    $category_link = get_category_link($category_id);
}

?>
```

Comment: It doesn't pull any info.

Answer (score 0):

You only ever end a `foreach`/`while` when you start it in short-hand. If you were to do it that way, your code would look like this:

```
foreach($category as $cat):
    query_posts( array ( 'cat' => $cat->cat_ID, 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 1  ) );
    while (have_posts()):
        the_post();
        echo '<a class="fulltitle" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.$cat->cat_name.'</a>';

    $category_id = get_cat_ID($cat->cat_name);
    $category_link = get_category_link($category_id);
    endwhile;

endforeach;
```

But since you've opened it up the programmatic way with your `{`, you do **not** need to use `endforeach` or `endwhile`. Simply close the brace `}`.

Comment: @ViciA You're only fetching **1** post, that's why it only shows one... -> `'posts_per_page' => 1 ` in your `query_posts()` function